# problem with capacitance measuring with stm32f103RE

Tags: stm32, adc, capacitance, keil

I'm trying to measure a capacitor's value and send it to the uart terminal. I'm using stm32f103re and I'm using registers. I attached the circuit I'm using and also my code.  the code is working now but the value of capacitance is a bit different than the value I get using the capacitance meter of the victor 88c multimeter. for a 10 nF ceramic capacitor, the victor 88c shows 12.22nF but the value I get with stm32 is 13.3.  I think it's because of the noise on ADC. what should I do to overcome this noise and get a more accurate value?

```
    #include "stm32f10x.h"
#include "stdio.h"

void SysTick_Handler (void);
void Delay_ms (uint32_t dlyTicks);
volatile uint32_t msTicks;
unsigned int value = 0;
int Data=0;

int counter=0;
char string[50];
char string2[50];
int time=0;
double charge_time=0;
double c=0;
double period=1.0/72000000;
int flag=0;
int val_Tx = 0;              /* Globals used for display */
int AD_last=0;
int flag2;


    char str[200];
    char data;




void ADC_Init (void) {

  RCC->APB2ENR |=(1<<2); /* enable periperal clock for GPIOA */
  GPIOC->CRL &= ~0xF0;                 /* set ADC1_IN1 (PA1) as analog input  */
//  /* Setup and initialize ADC converter                                       */
//  RCC->CFGR    |= ( 3UL << 14);           /* ADC clk = PCLK2 / 8              */

  RCC->APB2ENR |= ( 1UL <<  9);           /* enable periperal clock for ADC1  */

  ADC1->SQR1    =  0;                     /* Regular chn. Sequence length = 1 */
  ADC1->SQR2    =  0;                     /* Clear register                   */
ADC1->SQR3    = ( 1UL <<  0);           /* 1. conversion = channel 1        */
//  ADC1->SMPR2   = ( 5UL <<  3);           /* sample time channel 1  55,5 cyc. */
  //ADC1->CR1     = ( 1UL <<  8);           /* Scan mode on                     */
  ADC1->CR2     = ( 7UL << 17)         /* select SWSTART                   */
                  |( 1UL << 20) ;          // enable external Trigger          
//  ADC1->CR1    |= ( 1UL <<  5);/* enable for EOC Interrupt         */
//  NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC1_2_IRQn); /* enable ADC Interrupt             */
//  NVIC_SetPriority(ADC1_2_IRQn,1);
  ADC1->CR2    |= ( 1UL <<  0);           /* ADC enable                       */
ADC1->CR2    |= ( 1UL <<  1); 
  ADC1->CR2    |=  1 <<  3;               /* Initialize calibration registers */
  while (ADC1->CR2 & (1 << 3));           /* Wait for init to finish          */
  ADC1->CR2    |=  1 <<  2;               /* Start calibration                */
  while (ADC1->CR2 & (1 << 2));           /* Wait for calibration to finish   */
}

//// initialize usart
void usart_init(void) 
{
RCC->APB2ENR |=(1<<2); /* Enable GPIOA clock*/
RCC->APB2ENR |=(1<<14);  /* Enable USART1 clock*/
GPIOA->CRH   &= ~(0xFF <<  4);        /* clear PA9, PA10                  */
GPIOA->CRH   |=  (0xB <<  4);        /* USART1 Tx (PA9) alternate function output push-pull */
GPIOA->CRH   |=  (0x4 <<  8);        /* USART1 Rx (PA10) input floating  */
USART1->BRR=0x1D4C;     // baudrate 9600 assuming f=8MHz
USART1->CR1=((1<<2)|(1<<3)|(0<<12)|(1<<13));  // enable transmit and receive word length = 8 bit and usart enable 
//USART1->CR1  |= ( 1UL << 5);     // RXNE interrupt enable
//NVIC_SetPriority(USART1_IRQn,0); /* Default priority group 0, can be 0(highest) - 31(lowest) */
//NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);     /* Enable UART0 Interrupt */
    USART1->CR2   = 0x0000;                 /* 1 stop bit                       */
  USART1->CR3   = 0x0000;                 /* no flow control                  */
}   
    





void usart_sendchar(char data){
    while(!(USART1->SR&(1<<7)));
    USART1->DR=data;
}



void usart_sendstring(char *s) 
{
    while (*s) 
    {
    usart_sendchar(*s);
        s++;
    }
}


void Timer_init(void)
    {

RCC->APB2ENR |= (1<<11);             /* enable clock for TIM1    */

  TIM1->PSC   = ( 1 - 1 );   /* set prescaler   = 72000000Hz  */
  TIM1->ARR   = ( 1000 - 1);   /* set auto-reload = 13/89 us */
  TIM1->RCR   =  0;           /* set repetition counter   */

TIM1->DIER = (1<<0);   /* Update Interrupt enable  */
TIM1->CR1  |= (1<<0);   /* 0x0001 timer enable       */
NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM1_UP_IRQn);


  
//      NVIC_SetPriority(TIM1_UP_IRQn,1);
}


void TIM1_UP_IRQHandler (void) {

  if (TIM1->SR & (1<<0)) { /* UIF set    */

   
    time++;
    TIM1->SR &= ~0x1;         /* clear UIF flag           */
        
    }
 
}

int main()
{
    SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock/1000); // setup systick timer for 1ms interrupts
    usart_init();
    
RCC->APB2ENR |= (1<<3);
GPIOB->CRL &=~0xF0;
GPIOB->CRL |= 0x30;            //////// GPIOB.1  output


    
    
while (1)
{

    
if (flag==0){

Delay_ms(500);
GPIOB->BSRR=(1<<17);
Delay_ms(500);  
GPIOB->BSRR=(1<<1);
flag=1;
Timer_init();

ADC_Init();
ADC1->CR2    |=  (1<<22);         // start A/D conversion
}

else if (flag==1)
{

    if (ADC1->SR & (1 << 1)){
AD_last = ADC1->DR;
 val_Tx = (AD_last & 0xFFF);        /* use upper 12 bits of ADC  */
                if (val_Tx>2580)
                                {
                                    ADC1->CR2    &= ~(1<<22); /* stop A/D conversion     */
                    flag=0;
                  TIM1->CR1  &= 0;
                    counter=TIM1->CNT;
                    charge_time=(time*1000*period)+(counter*period);
                    c=10*charge_time;
                    sprintf(string,"the capacitance value is : %f uF\n", c);
                    sprintf(string2,"charge time is  %f\n time is %i\n counter is %i\n ",charge_time,time,counter);
                    usart_sendstring(string);
                    usart_sendstring(string2);
                                    
                    time=0;
                  flag=0;   
                  counter=0;
                 charge_time=0;
                 c=0;
                  ADC_Init();
               GPIOB->BSRR=(1<<17);
                  }
}
    
    
}
}   
    
}

void SysTick_Handler(void) {
    msTicks++;
}
void Delay_ms (uint32_t dlyTicks) {
    uint32_t curTicks;
    curTicks = msTicks;
    while ((msTicks - curTicks)< dlyTicks);
}
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

Comment: What does the user manual say about clearing interrupt flags? It might not be what you expect, so read carefully.

Comment: What is the actual value of the resistor? Please fix the indentation of your code, it is very difficult to read.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson the actual value of the resistor is 99.4k ohm so even if I correct that it doesn't change the capacitance value that much.